# Rational points of bounded height on a variety

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations, rational-points, diophantine-geometry

I would like to ask for some clarification on the following argument which I can not quite understand.

There is a variety $X$ of dimension $n$ over a number field with a degree two map $f:X\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{\frac{n}{2}}\times\mathbb{P}^{\frac{n}{2}}$ and a rational map $g:\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow X$. The map $f\circ g$ is given by $n+2$ polynomials of a certain degree, say $b$. Hence, if $p\in\mathbb{P}^n$ has height at most $B^{\frac{1}{b}}$ then its image has height at most $B$. So far so good.

Now comes the part that I do not get. This should imply that there is a $t > 0$ such that for any open subset $U\subset X$ the number of rational points of height at most $B$ in $U$ is at least $\lambda B^{t}$ for $B\gg 0$, where $\lambda > 0$ depends on $X$.

Why does the last statement hold true? Thank you very much.

The map $f\circ g$ is generically $b^n$ to one. So the map $g$ should be $\frac{b^n}{2}$ to one. Then the number of points of height at most $B$ of $X$ is at least the number of points of height at most $B^{\frac{1}{b}}$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ multiplied by $\frac{2}{b^n}$. I think at this point I should use an estimate on the number of points of height at most $B^{\frac{1}{b}}$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ which is unknown to me (probably a power of $B$). Even if I could do that I would not know where the $\lambda > 0$ depending on $X$ is coming from.

Also it seems that the map $f$ is not really necessary in this argument. One could reason on the polynomials defining $g:\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^N$.

Comment: Can you link to where the argument is written?

Comment: This argument has been told to me by a professor in my department. I asked him for a clarification but it seems he is unable to give me an understandable explanation. Probably because it is a trivial implication to him. I will add to my question my personal thoughts about the argument in case it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the situation, it's understandable that some stuff is missing from the argument.

One part that's missing is the *definition* of the height.

In modern language (Weil's height machine), we usually take a height function to be defined from an ordered pair of a variety *and a line bundle*, well-defined up to a constant factor, by the rule that if your line bundle is the pullback of $\mathcal O(1)$ along a map to $\mathbb P^n$ then the associated height is the pullback of the standard height function on $\mathbb P^n$, and height is multiplicative in tensor products of line bundles.

So to even formulate the question, you need to pick a line bundle.

The obvious line bundle on $X$ to work with is the pullback of $\mathcal O(1,1)$ from $\mathbb P^{n/2} \times \mathbb P^{n/2}$.

In that case, to prove the estimate for $X$, it suffices to prove the estimate for $\mathbb P^{n/2} \times \mathbb P^{n/2}$ since by the definition the height doesn't change when you go there. We only have to multiply by a factor of $2$, which will be independent of $X$.

There is a standard bound for heights in this situation. A point of height $<X$ on $\mathbb P^{n/2} \times \mathbb P^{n/2}$ can be written as $((a_0: \dots : a_{n/2}), (b_0:\dots : b_{n/2}))$ where the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are integers, each tuple is relatively prime, and $\max (a_i) \max(b_i)< X$. Thus we can take $\max(a_i) < 2^m$ and $\max(b_i) < 2^\ell$ where $m+l=\lceil \log_2(X) \rceil+1$. The number of choices of $m$ is  $\lceil \log_2(X) \rceil+2$ and then we have at most $2^{ (m+1) ( (n/2)+1)}$ possibilities for the $a_i$ and $2^{ (\ell+1) (n/2+1)}$ possibilities for the $b_i$ for $2^{ (m+\ell+2) ( n/2+1)} \leq X^{n/2+1} 2^{2n+4}$ possibilities in total. Summing over the options for $m$ and $\ell$, we get at most a constant times $X^{n/2+1} \log X$.

So we can take any $t> n/2+1$.

There are many things present that are not needed for this (the constant depending on $X$, the open set $U$, and the map from $\mathbb P^n$) so maybe something different was meant.

It is very hard to use the map from $\mathbb P^n$ to control the number of points of bounded height as, first, not all points need lie in the image of such a map (since it's rational and not necessarily well-defined everywhere), and, second, it's possible that the height of the image under the map could be lower than the height of the original point.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am confused about one thing. As you said you did not use the map from $\mathbb{P}^n$. But couldn't we have a variety $X$ with a rational map $X\dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{\frac{n}{2}}\times \mathbb{P}^{\frac{n}{2}}$ such that $X$ does not have points at all over the base field?

Comment: @Smy The statement we're trying to prove is that the number of rational points is at most something, so if $X$ has no points, that's not a problem.

Comment: I am really sorry. I wrote "at most" instead of "at least". My mistake, I feel silly.

Comment: @Smy Ah, I see. In this case you are right, we need a lower bound on rational points in $\mathbb P^n$. Such is provided by an argument similar to the one I gave, except you lower bound at each step instead of upper bound - the hardest part is counting relatively prime tuples of points, which isn't that hard. The constant could arise from the size of the coefficients in the $n+2$ tuple of polynomials of degree $b$.

Comment: I see. But then what about rational points of $\mathbb{P}^n$ lying in the indeterminacy locus of $g:\mathbb{P}^n\dashrightarrow X$? Clearly these do not give rational points on $X$. We could take $U$ as the open subset of $X$ where $g$ is defined by then we would have proved the claim for a particular open subset and not for any open subset.

Comment: @Smy We take an open subset of $\mathbb P^n$ defines as, within the open subset where $g$ is defined, the inverse image of $U$ in $X$. One can easily prove the lower bound for open subsets of $\mathbb P^n$ using crude upper bounds for the complementary closed set.